# meaningof the verb ''reflect in''

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, terminology

what is the meaning of the verb "reflect in" in this sentence:

> For a general
> $$z=re^{i\theta}$$ the image $$w={{1}\over{z}}$$ can be found geometrically by marking $$\left|{w}\right|={{1}\over{r}}$$on the segment from 0 to z and
> then **reflecting** the mark **in** the real axis.

Answer (score 4):

It means the reflection across the real axis which for $z=x + yi$ is the complex conjugate $x-yi$.

Comment: so it means: ''replacing a point on one side of the axis by the point symmetrically placed on the other side of the axis.'' am I right?

Comment: @Arashrostami Yes. The polar form shows us two things about the multiplicative inverse $1/z$. The radius will be $1/r$ and the angle will be $-\theta$. The fact that the angle is $-\theta$ is the same as saying it is the reflection about the real axis.

Comment: So, are "reflecting in", "reflecting across" and "reflecting about" synonyms here? Out of curiosity, would "reflecting with respect to" sound funny/weird/wrong?

Comment: @fitzcarraldo yeah they're synonyms and "reflecting with respect to" sounds boring/normal/right.

Comment: Thank you, @CyclotomicField... MSE is proving English teacher to me as much as math one.